# Overwrite font: in CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have an existing web page on which there is a CSS file that I am unable to change which has the following CSS in it:

```
body {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    color: #000000;
    font: 0.8em Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

I am adding in an additional CSS file, and for the part of the page that its controlling I need to be able to overwrite the font size that is above, and set the size to the auto size as supplied by the browser and a different font family.

I know about putting the `!important` tag on there so changing the font family hasn't been a problem, but if I don't put a size in there it strips it out when the page compiles.

I thought I could use `font-size:` to override it, but I'm unclear as to how to set that to be whatever the browser has automatically.

All help would be much appreciated! I'm a bit of a CSS novice!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
html body {
    /* your stuff here */
}
```

By using the html element, it makes the selector more specific and applies the overwrite.

Example:

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
}

html body {
    font-family: serif;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
Hello world.<br>
This is the 'normal' size because of the html element selector allowing an override.
```

Edit: The answer has been accepted but I changed the font-size to `1em`. As this is the initial body tag it should reset the the browser default size. This was asked in the question and I didn't cover this.

Answer (score 3):

You can make something more specific which will overwrite the styles, e.g

```
body div {
  font-family:Helvetica;
}
```

Also, `font-size`'s default value is `medium`. You can also use `initial`, but that isn't supported in IE.

```
body div {
  font-family:Helvetica;
  font-size:medium;
}
```

Comment: `initial` [isn't supported on IE](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_initial.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Well the default font-size is `medium`.

```
.wherever{
    font-size: medium;
}
```

That will overwrite the body font size that is added.

Answer (score 1):

Use `unset` to clear the font-size value:

```
body {
  font-size: unset;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**now you can try to this**

```
html body *{
  font-family: //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Sets default font family to Helvetica.
- Prevents iOS text size adjust after orientation change, without disabling user zoom.

  ```
   html  
      {
           font-family: Helvetica;
          -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
          -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;

      }

  body
   {
       font-size: 14px;
    }
  ```